# Django query optimization for 3 related tables

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-queryset

I have 4 models:

```
class Run(models.Model):
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True)
    end_time = models.DateTimeField()
    chamber = models.ForeignKey(Chamber, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe, default=None, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class RunProperty(models.Model):
    run = models.ForeignKey(Run, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    property_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    property_value = models.CharField(max_length=500)

class RunValue(models.Model):
    run = models.ForeignKey(Run, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    run_parameter = models.ForeignKey(RunParameter, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    value = models.FloatField(default=0)

class RunParameter(models.Model):
    parameter = models.ForeignKey(Parameter, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    chamber = models.ForeignKey(Chamber, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    param_name_user_defined = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

A `Run` can have any number of `RunProperty` (usually user defined properties, can be custom), and a few predefined `RunValue` (such as Average Voltage, Minimum Voltage, Maximum Voltage) that are numeric values.

The `RunParameter` is basically just a container of parameter names (Voltage, Current, Frequency, Temperature, Impedance, Oscillation, Variability, etc, there's a ton of them.

When I build a front end table to show each `Run` along with all of its "File" `RunProperty` (where the `Run` came from) and all of its "Voltage" `RunValue`, I first query the DB for all `Run` objects, then do an additional 3 queries for the Min/Max/Avg, and then another query for the File, then I build a dict on the backend to pass to the front to build the table rows:

```
runs = Run.objects.filter(chamber__in=chambers)
min_v_run_values = RunValue.objects.filter(run__in=runs, run_parameter__parameter__parameter_name__icontains="Minimum Voltage")
max_v_run_values = RunValue.objects.filter(run__in=runs, run_parameter__parameter__parameter_name__icontains="Maximum Voltage")
avg_v_run_values = RunValue.objects.filter(run__in=runs, run_parameter__parameter__parameter_name__icontains="Average Voltage")
run_files = RunProperty.objects.filter(run__in=runs, property_name="File")
```

This is not such a big problem for customer with ~10 to 30 `Run` objects in their database, but we have one heavy usage customer who has 3500 `Run` instances. Needless to say, it's far, far too slow. I'm doing 5 queries to get all the needed instances, and then I have to loop and put them together into one dict. It takes upwards of 45 seconds to do this for that one customer (and about 8 or 10 for most other customers).

Is there a way that I can query my DB for all `Run` objects along with all of the Min/Max/Avg Voltage `RunValue` and the File `RunProperty` and return, say, a list of dicts, one for each `Run` along with the other objects?

I think `Q` queries can be used here, but I'm not quite sure HOW to use them, or if they are applicable for this scenario?

I tried this (but didn't get far):

```
runs = Run.objects.filter(chamber__in=chambers)
v_query = Q(run_parameter__parameter__parameter_name__icontains="Voltage")
run_values = RunValue.objects.filter(run__in=runs).filter(v_query)
run_files = RunProperty.objects.filter(run__in=runs, property_name="File")
```

That gets me all the `RunValue` related objects in 1 query, but it's still 3 queries per. I need to optimize this much more, if possible.

I am looking for something along the lines of:

```
runs = Run.objects.filter(chamber__in=chambers)
        .annotate(Q(run__runvalue__run_parameter__parameter__parameter_name__icontains="Voltage")
                & Q(run__runproperty__property_name__icontains="File"))
```

I think in very broad terms (not even pseudocode) I would need a query like:

"Get all `Run`s, and for each `Run`, get all the `RunValue` objects related to that `Run` that contain ["Average", "Maximum", "Minimum"] and also all the `RunProperty` objects for that `Run` that contain "File".

I don't know if it's possible (sounds like it should be), and I'm not sure whether I should use Q filtering, aggregates or annotation. In broad terms, I need to get all instances of one model, along with all foreign keys for each instance, in one query, if possible

Example:

I have table `Run` with 2 instances:

```
R1
R2
```

Each `Run` instance has an associated RunProperty instance "File" (just a string) for each:

```
R1_run.dat
R2_run.dat
```

Each`Run` instance has many RunValue instances (I am using Voltage as an example, but there's 26 of them):

```
R1_max_v
R1_min_v
R1_avg_v

R2_max_v
R2_min_v
R2_avg_v
```

I would need to query the DB such that it returns (list or dict, I can work around either):

```
[{R1, R1_run.dat, R1_max_v, R1_min_v, R1_avg_v},
{R2, R2_run.dat, R2_max_v, R2_min_v, R2_avg_v}]
```

Or a 2D array even:

```
[[R1, R1_run.dat, R1_max_v, R1_min_v, R1_avg_v],
[R2, R2_run.dat, R2_max_v, R2_min_v, R2_avg_v]]
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: use annotate, select_related and prefetch_related.

Comment: I've been reading more on this and I believe this is what I have to do, query `Run` and annotate the other 2 tables. I just don't know how to do that.

Comment: you want average of voltage but you have mentioned it in models.

Comment: Oh, the average is already calculated. It's stored directly into its own table. It is calculated off of an entire different table and needs to be accessed frequently so we decided to create the `RunValue` table to store Avg/Max/Min per each `Run`, as to not calculate those each time through the annotate functions.

Comment: can you show this model "RunParameter"

Comment: I added the RunParameter, but it's basically a name container. A file is also a name of the file, it's not an actual FileField. Just identifiers in both cases.

I also added a broad example of what I'm looking for at the end of the post.

Answer (score 0):

From database perspective, you can get all the data you need using just a single query with a few joins:

```
-- This assumes that there is a primary key Run.id and 
-- foreign keys RunValue.run_id and RunProperty.run_id.
-- IDs or names of min/max/avg run parameters, as well as 
-- chamber ids are replaced with *_PARAMETER and CHAMBER_IDS 
-- for brevity.
SELECT Run.*, 
       RVmin.value AS min_value, 
       RVmax.value AS max_value,
       RVavg.value AS avg_value,
       RP.value AS file_value
FROM Run 
JOIN RunValue RVmin ON Run.id = RVmin.run_id
JOIN RunValue RVmax ON Run.id = RVmax.run_id
JOIN RunValue RVavg ON Run.id = RVavg.run_id
JOIN RunProperty RP ON Run.id = RP.run_id
WHERE
  RVmin.run_parameter = MIN_PARAMETER AND
  RVmax.run_parameter = MAX_PARAMETER AND
  RVavg.run_parameter = AVG_PARAMETER AND
  RP.property_name = 'File' AND
  Run.chamber IN (CHAMBER_IDS);
```

Django way of building such joins must be something like `Run.runvalue_set.filter(run_parameter__contains 'Maximum Voltage')`
See "following relationships backward": https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward

Answer (score 0):

You can get this in query by using `annotate`, `Min`, `Max`, `Avg`.

For your problem. You can do this.

Add related name in ForeignKey fields.

```
class RunProperty(models.Model):
    run = models.ForeignKey(Run, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="run_prop_name")

class RunValue(models.Model):
    run = models.ForeignKey(Run, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="run_value_name")
    run_parameter = models.ForeignKey(RunParameter, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    value = models.FloatField(default=0)
```

views.py

```
from django.db.models import Avg, Max, Min

filt = 'run_value_name__value'
query = Run.objects.annotate(run_avg = Avg(filt), run_max = Max(filt))
```

You can get all values:

```
  for i in query:
     print(i.run_avg, i.run_max, i.run_min )
```

**-----------Edit------------**

Please check I have added "related_name" in RunValue model.

let's assume you two values in **Run** model.

1) run_1

2) run_2

in model **RunValue**, 6 entries.

run = 1, run_parameter = "Avg_value", value = 50

run = 1, run_parameter = "Min_value", value = 25

run = 1, run_parameter = "Max_value", value = 75

run = 2, run_parameter = "Avg_value", value = 28

run = 2, run_parameter = "Max_value", value = 40

run = 2, run_parameter = "Min_value", value = 16

you want dictionary something like this:

```
{'run_1': {'Avg_value': 50, 'Min_value': 25, 'Max_value': 75}, 'run_2': {...}}
```

Do this remember to read `select_related` and `prefetch_related` for documentation.

```
    rt = Rub.objects.all().prefetch_related('run_value_name')
    s = {} # output dictionary
    for i in rt:
        s[i.run] = {} # run dictionary
        for j in i.run_value_name.all():

            s[i.run].update({j.run_parameter: j.value}) # update run dictionary

    print(s)
```

**----------Addition-----------**

Check number of database hit by this code.

```
from django.db import connection, reset_queries
print(len(connection.queries))
reset_queries()
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained, the Avg/Max/Min are already calculated, and stored as instances of `RunValue` as a `ForeignKey` to a `Run`.

Comment: @Mormoran value of Avg/Max/Min are static or will change if new instance is created?

Comment: They are static for that `Run`. The values are calculated on a different view, which happens only once, after that `Run` is finished (a `Run` is just a period during which we collect data). There are tons of different parameters we need to know the Avg/Max/Min for, I'm just using "Voltage" as an example, but there are 26 different parameters. That's why we decided to calculate them once and store them in a `ForeignKey`.

Comment: I think in very broad terms (not even pseudocode) I would need a query like:

"Get all Runs, and for each run, get all the RunValue objects related to that run that contain ["Avg", "Max", "Min"] and also all the RunProperty objects for that run that contain "File"

I don't know if it's possible (sounds like it should be), and I'm not sure whether I should use Q filtering, aggregates or annotation.

In broad terms, I need to get all instances of one model, along with all foreign keys for each instance, in one query, if possible.

Comment: @Mormoran, it is possible what you want but I am confused which model "file" coming from (you have not defined FileField), which model is for Avg/Max/Min. And values are already calculated, just use prefetch_related and normal query to get all.

Comment: The "File" is just a string, to indicate to the customer where that `Run` came from, think of it as just a string name, it's not really a file field.

Comment: @Mormoran, I have edited my answer. Please check if this helps.

Comment: @Mormoran, I have edited the answer. you can edit the queries as per your requirement.

Comment: I've tried with this solution, but `prefetch_related` will grab ALL `RunValue` instances related to the `Run`, not only the ones with `icontains="Voltage"`. It's a start, but is it possible to refine that further? `.prefetch_related('run_value_icontains__Voltage')` ??